# How would I use Automapper in this query?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, entity-framework, automapper

Given

```
      Dim postviewmodel As IEnumerable(Of be_PostsViewModel)

        postviewmodel = _postRepository.SelectAll.Select(Function(S) New
        be_PostsViewModel With {.PostIsPublished = S.PostIsPublished, .Id =
        S.PostId, .PostSummary = S.PostSummary, .PostDateCreated =
        S.PostDateCreated, 
       .PostCategory = S.PostCategory, .PostTitle =
        S.PostTitle}).Where(Function(p) 
        p.PostIsPublished = True).Where(Function(a) Not
        a.PostCategory.FirstOrDefault.CategoryName = "Lead Story")
       .Skip((Page - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize)
```

How would I use Automapper so I don't do all thmapping of properties by hand? I am completely new to it and have been doing a lot of reading but don't quite understand how to actually do it. I know I have to create the map and then call Mapper.map. But what goes where in Mapper.map?

Comment: Help us out a bit more. First format your code (add tabs, so we can read it), then explain which two types you want mapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Post, be_postsViewModel>();
```

Do that in your application startup (App_Start etc). Then in your code above:

```
postViewModel = _postRepository.SelectAll.Project.To(Of be_PostsViewModel)
```

However, I'd put the "Project.To" AFTER all of your Where/Skip/Take pieces. The projection is the last thing you want to do. Project.To creates that exact Select expression, passes it to the query provider to modify the SQL at its base.

Unless SelectAll doesn't return IQueryable, then you have other, larger problems.

Comment: Thanks Jimmy. My Select All does return IQueryable. Your ProjectTo got pointed in the right direction. Now I am trying to figure out how to map collections. But Thanks again!